# Spring security - implement switch account

Tags: spring, facebook, spring-mvc, spring-security

How could I implement switching accounts like Facebook ( Private Account -> Page Account ). 
The case would be identical to Facebook scenario: 
User logs in , create eg. a business account, and then he can switch to that account and continue as a company ( in order to change settings etc. ). Then he can switch back on personal account.

One company account could access multiple users (eg . Employees )

I would add that the only way to switch to the company account, is the earlier log in as user (no logon directly to the company's account - no password).

How could I implement that in Spring? Maybe spring security has similar functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Session. It supports multiple account logins in the browser.

> Multiple Browser Sessions - Spring Session supports managing multiple users' sessions in a single browser instance (i.e. multiple authenticated accounts similar to Google).

Docs here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/